# Install a new Xerox printer on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers

GM everybody.
I have a xerox b230 printer. I'm trying to add to ubuntu 23.10. I have the driver from Xerox but is in a zip file. I've extracted the zip and I have the driver in ppd. What next???

Thank you.

Comment: try 'gnome-settings'  then settings>printers

Comment: thank you, I'll try.